# Adding programatically more downloadable files for products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, download, woocommerce, product

I am trying to uploaded one more downloadable files in woocommerce product. I have already one downloadable file in my product and want to add one more.

For this I am using following code:

```
if($_FILES){
$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'abe_update_epub', $post_id );
    if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
        $errors = $attachment_id->get_error_messages();
        foreach( $errors as $error ){
            echo $error;
        }
    echo 'There was an error uploading the image';
    } else {
    // to get exiting file/Old file
    $abe_file = get_post_meta($abe_post_id, '_downloadable_files', true);
        foreach($abe_file as $abe){
            $name = $abe['name'];
            $url = $abe['file'];
        }
    // This is my new file which i want to upload also
        $file_name = 'Epub Files';
        $file_url1 = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
        $files[md5( $file_url )] = array(
            'name' => $file_name,
            'file' => $file_url
        );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable_files', $files );
        echo 'The image was uploaded successfully!';
    }
}
```

This function upload files in a correct way, **But it replace the old file by the new one.**

How I can solve this issue? 
What am I doing wrong in this script?

Thanks

Comment: @LoicTheAztec now it is working, thanks for saving my life. can i implement this for variation products uploading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> — **Definitive Update 3**
>
> **There was a lot of mistakes in your code:**
>
> In your code there is 2 mistakes in [**`get_post_meta()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function: 
>  
>   - Replaced **undefined `$abe_post_id`** by defined **`$post_id`**. 
>   - Removed third argument **`"true"`** as it's an array (NOT a string).
>
> The outputted array of **`$abe_file`** is a tri-dimensional array with a structure similar to this example:
>
> ```css
> array( 
>     0 => array(
>         "67f3fe902b6c55ac07b92ac804d1a9c8" => array(
>             "name" => "filename1"
>             "file" => "http://www.domain.tld/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce_uploads/2016/09/file1.pdf"
>         ),
>         "95ce074e798b2e9d6d0d4cbce02f0497" => array(
>             "name" => "filename2"
>             "file" => "http://www.domain.tld/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce_uploads/2016/09/file2.pdf"
>         )
>     )
> );
> ```

You don't need to iterate this array in a foreach loop as before, because you just want to insert your new file in it. You have to be sure that **`$post_id`** is the ID of your product (as **`$abe_post_id`** was undefined)…

This is the working updated code:

```
if($_FILES){
$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'abe_update_epub', $post_id );
    if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
        $errors = $attachment_id->get_error_messages();
        foreach( $errors as $error ){
            echo $error;
        }
        echo 'There was an error uploading the image';
    } else {

        // Get exiting array of downloadable files. IMPORTANT:
        // 1) => Removed "true" condition as it's an array (ot a string)
        // 2) => As "$abe_post_id" is not defined, I have replace it with "$post_id"
        $abe_file = get_post_meta($post_id, '_downloadable_files'); // removed "true"

        // NEW FILE: Setting the name, getting the url and and Md5 hash number
        $file_name = 'Epub Files';
        $file_url  = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
        $md5_num = md5( $file_url );

        // Inserting new file in the exiting array of downloadable files
        $abe_file[0][$md5_num] = array(
            'name'   =>  $file_name,
            'file'   =>  $file_url
        );

        // Updating database with the new array
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable_files', $abe_file[0] );

        // Displaying a success notice
        echo 'The image was uploaded successfully!';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update_post_meta rewrites meta in whole.

You should join old data ($abe_file) and new ($file) in new array and write it using update_post_meta.

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you help me how do i join in new array? i have tried but not success.