# What is the encryption used to store downloadable file in _downloadable_files meta key in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization, woocommerce

While making custom rest APIs for woocommerce store I found downloadable products are storing downloadable files into post_meta table with following format with key name _downloadable_files

```
a:1:{s:32:"6d42428daf0e1a7ffdc40b6fc8b310d2";a:4:{s:2:"id";s:32:"6d42428daf0e1a7ffdc40b6fc8b310d2";s:4:"name";s:8:"original";s:4:"file";s:77:"https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/fluteef0a289261ff7d8f4666732d862d91bf.mp3";s:13:"previous_hash";s:32:"6d42428daf0e1a7ffdc40b6fc8b310d2";}}
```

Can anyone please help how to figure out this encryption and so that I can make my own APIs for my project. I am stuck here to insert a new downloadable product from my rest api.

Thanks

Comment: Its not encryption its [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), are you on about the hashes?

Comment: yes correct how this id and hashes are generated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not encryption. It is just php serialized data.
So just do unserialize($data) while reading, and that's all.

Comment: Thanks mate you made my day!

Comment: Mate what about inserting ? How do you I create the Id or hash ? what is previous hash too ?

Comment: it can be done with md5. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39505952/701666

Comment: Great I understand now!